# makeeditable / jeditable: How can I use my own function for sAddURL

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I would like to use my own function for sAddURL and sDeleteURL instead of a URL.
I know it`s possible for updating a cell with sUpdateURL like this (see http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/custom-editors.html):

```
sUpdateURL: function(value, settings){
alert("Custom function for posting results");
return value;
}
```

but i haven`t found a way for adding and deleting a row.

I tried this but it throws an error: 405 (method not allowed).

```
sAddURL: function (value, settings) { 
return value;
}
```